# Angular http POST unable to send post parameters

Tags: php, angular, ionic3

This is what I'm using to make the call:

```
 const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  };

   this.http.post("https://fakedomain.com/info.php", { "uuid": this.device.uuid, "funcion": "saveFormulario"}, httpOptions).subscribe(response => {
    this.datos = response;
  });
```

And this is all the info the server is getting:

```
POST /info.php HTTP/1.0

HTTP headers:
Host: fakedomain.com
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: close
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://192.168.0.118:8100
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A372 Safari/604.1
Referer: http://192.168.0.118:8100/
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8

Request POST:

Request GET:

Request body:
{"uuid":"testuuid","funcion":"saveFormulario"}
```

So the info is getting sent, but nothing on the $_POST side.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the server response? Any exceptions in server logs?

Comment: Looks like a server side (php) issue, nothing to do specifically with angular. I would look at how your mapping is setup. You can isolate this more by using PostMan instead of angular as your testing client.

Comment: This might not be an angular issue. I am not a php guy and I am not sure if the params are case sensitive but perhaps you are using the wrong case for param names (uuid vs uuId, etc). Also make sure you are using the right spelling for second param, funcion vs function.

Comment: @Igor well in postman I can fake the call and receive the post data... Really weird.

Comment: Then compare the parameters in postman to what is being sent in angular. What is the difference?

Comment: @igor turns out the correct content type in angular was           'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Comment: what is the response http status code

Comment: @monxas so it solved now then? The angular client needed to send it in form encoding as req by the server?  Pls create the answer and accept so the question is closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what fixed the issue:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  })
};
```